# Функция для массива

Tags: php

Скажите какой функцию использовать чтобы выбрать нужный элемент массива например только показывать элемент только с именем Admin

```
  Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => fsddf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => User
        [user_status] => sdfsdds
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => sdfdsf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Vidal
        [user_status] => dsfsdfdf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
```

Comment: Не уверен в существовании встроенной функции для этого. Напишите свою функцию которая будет возвращать массив из массивов в которых user == 'Admin'. 

Можно через цикл сделать или array_map() какой-нибудь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = Array
        (
            Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => fsddf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => User
        [user_status] => sdfsdds
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => sdfdsf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Vidal
        [user_status] => dsfsdfdf
        [status_timestamp] => 
    )

        )

    var_export(array_filter($array, function($v) {
      return $v['name'] == 'Admin';
    }));
```

Результат:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    [id] => 6
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => fsddf
        [status_timestamp] => 
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    [id] => 4
        [name] => Admin
        [user_status] => sdfdsf
        [status_timestamp] => 
  ),
```

)

Так пайдет?:)